# Erlang conversion binary join?

Tags: erlang, erl

How to convert that binary format  to this `[<<"xys">>,<<"est">>]  -> [<<"xys","est">>].`

Answer (score 4):

Since [<<"xys","est">>] is the same as [<<"xysest">>] you can do:

```
1> [A,B] = [<<"xys">>,<<"est">>].   
[<<"xys">>,<<"est">>]
2> [<<A/binary, B/binary>>].
[<<"xysest">>]
```

Comment: i want the ans like this [<<"xys","est">>

Comment: [<<"xysest">>] == [<<"xys","est">>]. There is no other way to put it : those are two expressions for the same "thing". If this is unsatisfactory to you, consider revising how to handle binary data in erlang.